# Why does HttpSecurity configuration via DSL not seem to work the same as explicit configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, dsl

I went through the trouble to write a DSL to configure the `HttpSecurity` for my custom authentication mechanism, but most of the configuration I apply to it doesn't seem to be in effect when the application runs, while everything works perfectly when I configure it all manually in the webapp.

First, the manual configuration, which results in my `EntryPoint` firing, `authenticationProvider` being queried, the filter being added to the chain, and my `rememberMeServices` being added to that filter.  Everything correct.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/auth/callback").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .rememberMe()
          .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
          .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
          .and()
        .addFilterAfter(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    /* The following code is basically what gets run when the DSL is in use
    http
        .apply(new EPIdentityDsl())
          // lots of setters called here, removed for clarity
          .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    */
  }

}
```

However, the code in the DSL looks like this, and when it is used, the `authenticationEntryPoint` never fires.  The `rememberMeServices` do get configured, and it looks like the filter gets added to the chain correctly, but I just get an error page for a 403 response instead of seeing the `entryPoint` redirection.

```
public class EPIdentityDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<EPIdentityDsl, HttpSecurity> {
  @Override
  public void init(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // any method that adds/removes another configurer
    // must be done in the init method
    log.debug("dsl init");
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
          .and()
        .rememberMe();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers(filterProcessesUrl).permitAll()
          .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
          .and()
        .rememberMe()
          .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
          .and()
        .addFilterAfter(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

  }
}
```

Clearly, there's some subtle interaction that I'm missing in the documentation or something, causing my DSL-based configuration of `entryPoint` to get lost. Any idea why?  If I had to guess, it would be that I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm specifying paths, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Got the exact same problem :) My dsl sets the authentication entry point but it is not used at runtime...

Comment: Got the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by moving entryPoint to init