# Add Basic Auth with oauth2Login

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication

In my spring boot application we've currently 2 types of accesses, `permitAll` for a handful of URIs stored in `String[] ALLOWED_WITHOUT_AUTHENTICATION`.

For rest (/**), we've applied `oauth2Login`. Then we added a `securityContext`.

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  
  .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(ALLOWED_WITHOUT_AUTHENTICATION).permitAll()

  .and().authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
  .and().oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(myOidcUserService).customUserType(MyOidcUser.class, "customUser")
  .and().defaultSuccessUrl(authSuccessURL, true).failureUrl(userNotAuthenticatedURL)
  .and().securityContext().securityContextRepository(new CookieSecurityContextRepository(myAuthCookieHelper))
  .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(getAuthenticationEntryPoint());
```

Now I want to added basic authentication for few URIs stored in `String[] AUTHENTICATED_WITH_BASIC_AUTH`.

So I've written below code :

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  
  .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(ALLOWED_WITHOUT_AUTHENTICATION).permitAll()

  .and().authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers(Constants.AUTHENTICATED_WITH_BASIC_AUTH).authenticated()
  .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(myBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())
  .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")

  .and().authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
  .and().oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(myOidcUserService).customUserType(MyOidcUser.class, "customUser")
  .and().defaultSuccessUrl(authSuccessURL, true).failureUrl(userNotAuthenticatedURL)
  .and().securityContext().securityContextRepository(new CookieSecurityContextRepository(myAuthCookieHelper))
  .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(getAuthenticationEntryPoint());
```

But I do not want to apply `securityContext` to URIs which are authenticated with basic auth.

How can I segregate these two?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52606913/3761628