# Spring AuthenticationManager and circular dependency

Tags: java, spring

I am in a situation were I need two login mechanisms for a single endpoint.
I have applied the suggestion from
[Using multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114269/using-multiple-websecurityconfigureradapter-in-spring-boot) and have now ran into an issue wit the `AuthenticationManager`.

The `AuthenticationManager` lives in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and is needed in the implementation of the `ServiceWebSecurityConfigurer`. However the `ServiceWebSecurityConfigurer` is used in the implementation of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` making a circular dependency.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UnitedSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private List<ServiceWebSecurityConfigurer> serviceWebSecurityConfigurers;

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    serviceWebSecurityConfigurers.forEach(configurer -> configure.config(http));
  }

  @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration implements ServiceWebSecurityConfigurer {
  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Bean
  public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();

  // AuthenticationManager needed here
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    
    return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
  }
}
```

How can I get out of this situation?

Comment: Why are you specifying an override that does nothing obvious?

Comment: The override of authenticationManagerBean() is because AuthenticationManager is not a bean - hence the @Bean annotation

Comment: If you're using the latest Spring, the need for `@Autowired` fields on configuration classes has been removed, and I suggest you take it out. That said, have you tried using `@Lazy` on either `serviceWebSecurityConfigurers` or `authenticationManager`?

Comment: I did not know @Lazy - this was the trick. If you add an answer I will accept it :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To very simply address your most pressing issue, make one of the references `@Lazy`; this tells Spring to use a lazy proxy, which can resolve circularity problems. I strongly recommend doing it this way:

```java
@Bean
public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter(
  @Lazy AuthenticationManager authenticationManager // use parameters instead of fields
) { ... } // don't use unnecessary throws clauses
```